# authlogic argument out of range on login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authlogic, activesupport

I'm updating from Rails 3.2 to 4.

When The user authenticate, that rise an error "argument out of range" on the **@user_session.save**

```
def create
 @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])    
  if @user_session.save
    flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
    redirect_back_or_default account_url
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

**EDIT 1**
Here is the UserSession model

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  include ActiveModel::Conversion  

  before_destroy :reset_persistence_token
  before_create  :reset_persistence_token

      def reset_persistence_token
          record.reset_persistence_token
      end 

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def to_key
      new_record? ? nil : [ self.send(self.class.primary_key) ]
  end

end
```

**EDIT 2** Here is the console message if it can help :

```
Started POST "/user_session" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-28 17:31:55 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by UserSessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jgjhvhgfztdrtdts4354367574dd3w=", "user_session"=>{"username"=>"test", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "submit"=>""}
ApplicationController::current_user_session
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = 'Ruffieux' ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 206ms

ArgumentError - argument out of range:
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:286:in `parse'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/zones.rb:8:in `in_time_zone'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:37:in `current_login_ip='
   () Users/p3889/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@skill4/bundler/gems/authlogic-e4b2990d6282/lib/authlogic/session/magic_columns.rb:61:in `update_info'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__3103588262215272643__before_save__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
   () Users/p3889/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@skill4/bundler/gems/authlogic-e4b2990d6282/lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:84:in `before_save'
   () Users/p3889/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@skill4/bundler/gems/authlogic-e4b2990d6282/lib/authlogic/session/existence.rb:68:in `save'
  app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:12:in `create'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:453:in `_run__3656350987262664205__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3906969335337569179__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/p3889/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/p3889/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/p3889/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What is in your `UserSession` model? And what is the content of `params[:user_session]`?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Rails 4.0. `current_login_ip` is a string field that `Authlogic` attempts to write to, but somehow triggers timezone conversion in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb, 
leading to

```
Time.parse request.ip
```

which obviously fails. According to [ActiveRecord::Timestamp](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html), Rails must have regarded `current_login_ip` as a time zone aware attribute.

Quickfix:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:current_login_ip]
end
```

Comment: Thank for your response. I've moved back to rails 3.2 for the moment and cannot test your solution for now. But I will give you a feed-back when I update again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like maybe your `current_login_ip` and `last_login_ip` are set to a datetime type, when it should be a string.